# Replacing part of ${url}'s from a sitemap in Jmeter

Tags: regex, testing, xpath, jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan that goes to a site's sitemap.xml page, retrieves each url on that page with an XPath Extractor, then passes ${url} to a HTTP Request sampler within a ForEach Controller to send the results for each page to a file.  This works great, except I just realized that the links on this sitemap.xml page are hardcoded. This is a problem when i want to test https://staging-website.com, but all of the links on sitemap.xml are all www.website.com pages. It seems like there must be a way to replace 'www.website.com' in each ${url} with 'staging-website.com' with regex or something, but I haven't been able to figure out how.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a BeanShell pre-processor to manipulate the url.

```
        String sUrl = vars.get("url");
        String sNewUrl = sUrl.replace("www.website.com", "https://staging-website.com");
        log.info("sNewUrl:" + sNewUrl);
        vars.put("url", sNewUrl);
```

You can also try to correlate the sitemap.xml with the regular expression extractor positioned till www.website.com so that you extract only the URL portion of the data instead of the full host name. Shouldn't you be having it already since the HTTPSampler only allows you to enter the URI segment and not the host name?

Comment: I am new to JMeter and I don't really understand where to put the BeanShell pre-processor to do that replace on each of the url's before testing them.  When i put it as a preprocessor for the HTTP Request within the ForEach Controller, it does not work.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: As per your description, you are using XPath Extractor to pull the URL. Once you have pulled it, you will be submitting it in the next HTTP Request sampler to get the contents of that URL that you obtained from XPath Extractor. In that second HTTP Sampler, you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) function available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project like:

```
${__strReplace(${url},${url},staging-website.com,)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Replace String]

The easiest way to install JMeter Custom Functions (as well as any other plugins) is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager - Custom Functions]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace the host within the string by putting

```
${__javaScript('${url}'.replace('www.website'\,'staging.website'))}
```

in the path input of the second http request sampler.  The answers provided by Selva and Dimitri were more elegant, so if I have time in the future to come back to this I will give them another try. I really appreciate the help!